# Android Manifest Default Activity not found

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.gmail.mansur.project">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/mylogo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"

        >
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Mansur"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Mansur"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="Bilgi Teknolojileri"
            android:logo="@mipmap/mylogo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText" />


        <service

            android:name="com.example.myapplicationservices.MyApplicationService"
            android:enabled="true"

            android:exported="false" />
        <!--android:stopWithTask="false"-->


    </application>

</manifest>



// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

  ext {
    release = [
            versionName: "6.1.1",
            versionCode: 6101
    ]

    setup = [
            compileSdk: 28,
            buildTools: "28.0.3",
            minSdk    : 14,
            targetSdk : 28
    ]

    versions = [
            androidX: '1.0.0',
            constraintLayout: '1.1.3'
    ]
  }


  repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

  }
  dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'


//    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'


  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {

        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.gmail.mansur.project"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.1'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

//        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "MaterialDrawer-v$versionName-c$versionCode")

    }
    buildTypes {

//        debug {
//            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
//            versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
//            try {
//                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
//            } catch (ex) {
//            }
//            minifyEnabled false
//        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/android.support.design_material.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.transition_transition.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.print_print.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version'

        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.cardview_cardview.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/com.google.android.material_material.version'
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }

    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
//    lintOptions {
//        abortOnError false
//    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

//   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation project(':myapplicationwebapi')
    implementation project(':myapplicationservices')
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.leinardi:FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:master-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.1'
    implementation project(':recyclerrefreshlayout')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'





    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'


    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:${versions.constraintLayout}"



    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

    // the sample uses more advanced functions of the fastadapter
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-commons:3.3.0'
    // used to generate the Open Source section
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.2.0'

    //used to provide different itemAnimators for the RecyclerView
    //https://github.com/mikepenz/ItemAnimators
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:1.1.0'
    // used to provide the MiniDrawer to normal Drawer crossfade effect via a SlidingPane layout
    // --> https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/MiniDrawerActivity.java
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/Crossfader
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:crossfader:1.6.0'
    // used to provide the two step crossfade DrawerLayout. Which allows to have a mini layout which transforms to a normal layout within the drawer
    // --> https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/CrossfadeDrawerLayoutActvitiy.java
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/CrossfadeDrawerLayout
    implementation('com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:1.1.0')



    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.3.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.3.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.2.0.5@aar'

//font
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:meteocons-typeface:1.1.0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:2.7.94.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:weather-icons-typeface:2.0.10.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:typeicons-typeface:2.0.7.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:entypo-typeface:1.0.0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:devicon-typeface:2.0.0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:foundation-icons-typeface:3.0.0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:ionicons-typeface:2.0.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:pixeden-7-stroke-typeface:1.2.0.3@aar'




    implementation 'com.nikhilpanju.recyclerviewenhanced:recyclerviewenhanced:1.1.0'
//    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.1.0"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.mikepenz:fastadapter:3.3.0"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:${versions.androidX}"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.androidX}"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${versions.androidX}"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${versions.androidX}"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:design:${versions.androidX}"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:${versions.androidX}"
}
```

I have tried:

1-İnvalidate Caches / Restart 
2-Check Filter intent
3-Manifest delete after created
4-Clean Project/Rebuild Project

I couldn't find the solution to the problem , i did sync gradle but not improved. Also added in manifest "" didn't work again :)

Help me thank you :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVpJH.png)

Comment: added in manifest  android.intent.category.DEFAULT didn't work again

Comment: Can you check if your default activity `FirstActivity` has package name of `com.gmail.mansur.project`?

Comment: I have erased the gradle and created it again , improved..

Comment: thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You could move

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>
```

to another activity, and click `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`,  then clicking on `Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: I have erased the gradle and created it again , improved..
thanks for your comment